# Checking Map for two condtions using filter

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have a map with collegeID and Student Id

I am checking if the Map has both the keys and values associated with them

This is always giving false

This is my code

```java
Map<String, String> allDataMap = new HashMap<>();
allDataMap.put("college_id", "1095");
allDataMap.put("student_id", "108");

boolean present = allDataMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(map -> map.getKey().equals("college_id") && map.getValue().equals("1095"))
    .filter(map -> map.getKey().equals("student_id") && map.getValue().equals("108"))
    .findAny().isPresent() ? true : false;

System.out.println(present);
```

Comment: What exactly do you think `filter` does?

Comment: Sure, this is giving false because the condition is applied to each entry in the map and one cannot have different keys or values. Does you _have_ to use a stream for this? Depending on the size of a map a stream could be very inefficient as you're basically replacing O(1) access with O(n) iteration.

Comment: A simple non-stream solution could be: `allDataMap.getOrDefault("college_id","").equals("1095") && allDataMap.getOrDefault("student_id","").equals("108")`. However, this feels like it's based on a design problem, i.e. you seem to be looking for a certain student - why do you represent students as maps?

Comment: Btw, `boolean present = ....isPresent()?true:false` - you're converting a boolean into a boolean - why? Just use `boolean present = .... isPresent()` (when appropriate in the first place).

Answer (score 3):

The two filters are mutual exclusive, so no element of your `Stream` can pass both of them. Therefore you get `false`.

You can use a single filter:

```
boolean present =  allDataMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(map-> (map.getKey().equals("college_id") && map.getValue().equals("1095")) || 
                  (map.getKey().equals("student_id") && map.getValue().equals("108")))
    .count() == 2;
```

Note that this relies on the source of the `Stream` being a `Map`, which means no key can appear twice, so if the `Stream` has exactly two elements after applying the filter, this means both key-value pairs appear in the source `Map`.

In general `Stream`s this won't necessarily return the correct result, since the same key-value pair might appear twice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a stream that at all, as *@Thomas* has pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73726418/checking-map-for-two-condtions-using-filter/73727186#comment130189229_73726418).

Checking two values in a `HashMap` is a constant time **`O(1)`** action, but iterating over map entries takes **`O(n)`**. And the latter option requires having the same conditional logic inside the stream. Definitely, employing a stream would buy you nothing in this case.

The following condition would be concise and straightforwards:

```
boolean present = "1095".equals(allDataMap.get("college_id"))
                && "108".equals(allDataMap.get("student_id"));
```

***Note:** if argument passed to the* `String.equals()` *is* `null`, *method call would return* `false`.